# How to parse UTC time stamp and convert into another format in java

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, utc

Hi i have UTC time stamp and i need parse to convert it into IST format 
I use to receive UTC time stamp from MSC (Telecom base station) in the form of `string : 1307261822062B0530` and it can be divide as bellow

```
13 07 26 18 22 06 2B 05 30

yy  =   13
MM  =   07
DD  =   26
hh  =   18
mm  =   22
ss  =   06
S   =   2B (how do iconvert this value into + / -)
hh  =   05 
mm  =   30
```

The problem is converting sign (+/-) to add or subtract on received universal time

i am trying to parse as bellow

```
public static String formatRawTimeStamp(String rawTimeStamp){

      String[] arr_msisdn = rawTimeStamp.split("(?<=\\G.{2})"); // split every two character  
      String formatedDate = "";
      Date date;
      DateFormat srcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ssZ");
      DateFormat desFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

      if(arr_msisdn.length >= 6){

        try {

            date = (Date)srcFormat.parse(arr_msisdn[0]+"-"+arr_msisdn[1]+"-"+arr_msisdn[2]+" "+arr_msisdn[3]+":"+arr_msisdn[4]+":"+arr_msisdn[5]+"."+arr_msisdn[6]+""+arr_msisdn[7]+""+arr_msisdn[8]);
            formatedDate = desFormat.format(date);

        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      return formatedDate;
  }
```

But i am getting exception

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "13-07-30 18:45:11.2b0530"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:354)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.util.ASNUtil.formatRawTimeStamp(ASNUtil.java:199)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.util.MOCallEvent.decode(MOCallEvent.java:187)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.util.ZTEASN1DecodeApp.decode(ZTEASN1DecodeApp.java:114)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.util.ZTEASN1DecodeApp.main(ZTEASN1DecodeApp.java:80)
```

Hear it unable to parse `"2b"` value it indicate sign (+/-)

```
S   =   Sign 0 = “+”, “-“       ASCII encoded
```

how can i solve this. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply replace the characters before parsing?

```
String input = "1307261822062B0530";
String adjusted = input.replaceAll("2[Bb]", "+").replaceAll("2[Aa]", "-");

DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyMMddHHmmssZ");
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(adjusted, fmt); //2013-07-26T18:22:06+05:30
```

I have assumed that the input can contain `2B` or `2b` for `+` and `2A` or `2a` for `-`.

If you want to use a simpledateformat, the same logic can be applied.

Comment: is there is a way to identify / convert exactly what kind of sign 2B / 2A indicate

Comment: possibly ur assumption is write, just i seen this link https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apis/rest-api-v2/requirements/specifying-time-range-v2#utc

Comment: if you get any information about identifying  exactly what kind of sign 2B / 2A indicate pleas post hear

Comment: Currently i am working on ASN.1 Encoding/ Decoding using Bouncy Castle API

Comment: @RajeshHatwar On the link you shared, the examples is calling a rest api - the %2B is simply the URL encoding of `+`. If you are calling that API you should not have to do anything and the conversion from + to %2B should be done by your rest client.

Comment: And the response to a call seems to be in JSON format so there should not be any `%2B` in the response.

Comment: Sorry tats only link with 2B i seen while searching but i am not using REST API rather i am working on encoding / decoding CDRS using ASN.1 syntax which is generated by MAC (Base station in telecom)

Comment: Sorry I don't know what CDRS or ASN.1 are. Good luck!